# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException MobileServicesClient RegisterAsync

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

I have followed ever tutorial out there and I have come up with this...

It is a device registration method, using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient.RegisterAsync, It should send a device token to a server and register with an Azure Notification Hub.

This is my code:

```
    async Task SendRegistrationToServerAsync(NSData deviceToken)
    {
        // This is the template/payload used by iOS. It contains the "messageParam"
        // that will be replaced by our service.
        const string templateBodyAPNS = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"$(messageParam)\"}}";

        var templates = new JObject();
        templates["genericMessage"] = new JObject
        {
            {"body", templateBodyAPNS}
        };
        var token = deviceToken.Description.Trim('<', '>').Replace(" ", "").ToUpperInvariant();
        var client = new MobileServiceClient(App.MobileServiceUrl);
        var push = client.GetPush();

        // token = "530FE16E53C9BCC93FC41C3A1AFB6FCE41F9078F1AC82D1C70B019E3B798CDD6"
        // Error Happens Here - Line Below
        await push.RegisterNativeAsync(token);

    }
```

Throws

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
>   Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: what specific line throws the error?  and what does the data you're parsing look like?

Comment: await push.RegisterNativeAsync(token);

Comment: parsing a string

Comment: what are the CONTENTS of the string?  Is it valid json?

Comment: I am passing this string value to a function - of which I cannot find the code for (it's in a nugget package), the data it 530FE16E53C9BCC93FC41C3A1AFB6FCE41F9078F1AC82D1C70B019E3B798CDD6"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some unwanted characters inside your string. 
Please try this code:

```
        var DeviceToken = deviceToken.Description;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DeviceToken))
        {
            DeviceToken = DeviceToken.Trim('<').Trim('>');
        }
```

Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: I have removed '<' & '>' already, and the DeviceToken is not null. So I'm not entirely sure if it is todo with unwanted characters, as I can pass a device token as NSData straight into RegisterNativeAsync

Comment: What does this line returns you ?
`var push = client.GetPush();` ??

Comment: It returns the push object from mobileserviceclient, I haven't had any problems with this line, only when I try push.RegisterNativeAsync()